# iptables local machine to proxy for exact destination

Tags: debian, iptables, proxy

How I can redirect traffic for specific ip via proxy?

tried:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING --dst ip_of_destination -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to myproxy_ip:8888
```

but it won't route local traffic to my proxy.

Answer (score 0):

If `myproxy_ip` isn't the host itself, you probably need to do `MASQUERADE` in the `POSTROUTING` chain as well:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING --dst myproxy_ip -p tcp --dport 8888 -j MASQUERADE
```

Otherwise the proxy will probably route its replies wrongly.